# How to have Counter count the correct strings

Tags: python, json, counter

I am trying to get the counter to count which date appears most in the code below.

```
from collections import Counter

with open('dates.json', 'rb') as f:
    data = f.readlines()

c = Counter(data)
print (c.most_common()[:10])
```

the JSON data is stored as a list like

```
["Sun Aug 07 01:50:13 +0000 2016", "Sun Aug 07 01:50:13 +0000 2016", "Sun Aug 07 01:50:13 +0000 2016", "Sun Aug 07 01:50:13 +0000 2016", "Sun Aug 07 01:50:13 +0000 2016", "Sun Aug 07 01:50:13 +0000 2016", "Sun Aug 07 01:50:13 +0000 2016", "Sun Aug 07 01:50:13 +0000 2016", "Sun Aug 07 01:50:13 +0000 2016"]
```

I would expect the output to be something similar to this (grabbed from another program)

```
[('Sun Aug 07 02:29:45 +0000 2016', 4), ('Sun Aug 07 02:31:05 +0000 2016', 4), ('Sun Aug 07 02:31:04 +0000 2016', 3), ('Sun Aug 07 02:31:08 +0000 2016', 3), ('Sun Aug 07 02:31:22 +0000 2016', 3)]
```

But this is my output

```
[(48, 72), (32, 53), (49, 27), (34, 18), (117, 18), (58, 18), (65, 9), (51, 9), (103, 9), (43, 9)]
```

I dont really understand what its counting there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `readlines()`, you should use `json.load()` to load the JSON data into a Python list:

```
import json

with open('dates.json', 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
```

Comment: now we have the error TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'